# Creating empty object in Java?

Tags: java, object

How do you go about doing this? Is it as simple as this:

```
Name myName = new Name();
```

I'm a little confused. It should be a class with no instance variables.  I simply have to "create an empty object". The constructor will also be empty of course.

Comment: What is an "empty object" by your definition?

Comment: yes it is as simple as that but as Kepani asked, what are targeting at. You should elaborate on your understanding

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question as it is extremely vague. Objects either exist or don't (null). Empty likely depends on the class you're working with, something you're not showing us. Please clarify just what you're asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `Name` has a parameterless constructor, sure.  Whether or not it's "empty" depends on what that constructor does or what defaults it may have.

How do you define "empty object" anyway?

For example, if you want a variable but don't want it to actually have an object, you can just declare the variable without initializing it:

```
Name myName;
```

In this case `myName` will be `null` (or "unassigned"? depends on the context), but will be of type `Name` and can be used as such later (once it's assigned a value).

All the variable itself does is point to a location in memory where the "object" exists.  So something like `Name myName` doesn't "create" an object, it just creates the pointer to a memory location.  `new Name()` actually creates an object by calling its constructor.  When used together like in your example, the latter half creates the object and then the former half points to the location in memory where the object exists.

Comment: So would this work `public name()`

Comment: @JavaNewb: "work" in what context?  That looks like a declaration for a constructor (though my Java is a bit rusty), but it's missing the constructor body.  Without a more complete context it's difficult to say whether that statement is correct or not.

Comment: Work, as in the correct way to go about writing it. Sorry! The constructor is to remain blank and not have a body. I think this is correct and I was over analyzing the question, nothing new. On to my next head ache.

Answer (score 8):

An "empty object" is pretty ambiguous in java terms. I could interpret that as this:

```
Object empty = new Object();
```

which is about the emptiest object you can create.

However in your example,

```
Name myName = new Name();
```

That's going to create an object based on whatever code you've put in your default constructor. (Which, i guess if you're setting everything to a default value, is pretty empty)

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean by empty. What you have done is instantiated an object. If the objects constructor initialized the fields of the Name object then the objects fields have values assigned to them. Also the memory for these fields was allocated when you called new. So even if you havent assigned values to them they do in fact exist in memory but are simply not initialized.

Comment: Fields in an new object are initialized; if you don't assign anything to them, they will be initialized to 0, `false`, or `null`.